# How do i get real time messages with Axios in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.get('http://MYIP/MYURL',{
  auth: {
    username: 'user',
    password:'pass'
  }
})
      .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
         /*  console.log(auth);
          console.log(user); */

          // ... do something with the response
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log('teste')
      });
```

This is my code. Im connecting with this URL. The thing is, it returns me messages constantly,and i would like to get their return with axios in real time. Connect once and listen to the return from the URL in real time until i close the connection. How can i do that?

Comment: Use WebSockets for continuous data feeds. You *could* do long polling witch fetch, but WebSockets are the intended mechanism for data over time unless you use RTC.

Comment: And do you know how should i do the exact same thing with websockets? I have tried using 'ws' library, but it only accepts urls that start with 'ws://'' and that is not my case...

Comment: If you dont have control over the endpoint, then you'll just have to fetch over and over using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Comment: You could also use an EventStream (SSE). Less hassle than Websockets, but like mentioned above, you need to control the server side.

Comment: How do i use an event stream? I have found some material online but i had no success. Is there an specific library for it?